# Hoe to make an ImageButton with a label ontop clickable

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

So I've run into a problem with Imagebuttons in XAML. 
I usually render a background image from photoshop and then use this button everywhere and just add a label ontop that says what it does: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bjNE.jpg)

This here for isntance comes from this code (partially):

```
<!--Grid for button-->
<Grid Grid.Row="1" >
      <ImageButton
           x:Name="btn_register_mainpage"
           Source="btn_emptydummy.png" BackgroundColor="#00000000"/>
      <Label
          FontFamily="arial"
          TextColor="#272727"
          Text="Profil erstellen" 
          HorizontalOptions="Center" 
          VerticalOptions="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

Now, this works just fine, unless you want to click on it. 
As you can see I gave the button a name, I can now catch that name in code and delegate a click to it:

```
btn_register_mainpage.Clicked += async delegate
{
      await Navigation.PushAsync(new Screen_EditInformation());
};
```

However, this only works when the user clicks on the button - but NOT on the label since this is on top and has no click assigned to it.

So, what I could do is just assign the same click event to both objects (the label and the image button) but that seems rather unusual.

What is the best way to have a custom image as a button with a label ontop that is clickable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a **TapGestureRecognizer** on the label .

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" >

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>

            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <ImageButton
                Clicked="Button_Clicked"
                Grid.Row="0"
                        x:Name="btn_register_mainpage"
                         BackgroundColor="LightBlue"/>
            <Label
                Grid.Row="0"
                        FontFamily="arial"
                        TextColor="#272727"
                        Text="Profil erstellen" 
                        HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                        VerticalOptions="Center">

                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer
            Tapped="Button_Clicked"
            NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
                </Label.GestureRecognizers>

            </Label>
        </Grid>
```

Comment: This is actually a good solution, however: Now the click animation is only triggerd when clicked on the button. If I click the label, it works ofc, but no click animation is visible ... :)

Comment: Why don't you use button and set title directly ?

Comment: If you just want to set the `CornerRadius` , it is unnecessary to use ImageButton .

Comment: If i use text directly, I cannot alter the properties of the label (such as type, font) .. I will accept when it was correct dont wrry :)

Comment: Font is available in Button .

Answer (score 2):

You can add [GestureRecognizers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/tap) to any control in Xamarin.Forms. In your case you could add one to the Grid layout

**YourView.xaml**

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" >
    <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer
            Tapped="OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped"
            NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
    </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
    <ImageButton
        x:Name="btn_register_mainpage"
        InputTransparent="True"
        Source="btn_emptydummy.png" BackgroundColor="#00000000"/>
    <Label
        FontFamily="arial"
        TextColor="#272727"
        Text="Profil erstellen" 
        HorizontalOptions="Center" 
        VerticalOptions="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

**YourView.xaml.cs**

```
private void OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Navigation.PushAsync(new Screen_EditInformation());
}
```

Comment: Can you add the corresponding c# code to catch the click? :)

Comment: I added the event handler

Comment: Wierdly enought, this only works when I click the label now, not if I click on the button around it...

Comment: That is weird. Try adding  InputTransparent="True" to the ImageButton, that should get rid of this problem